# iMacros Chrome not recognizing download path

Tags: imacros

I've got Chrome set to download to a specific folder by default, I've set both the iMacros browser and the iMacros chrome extension to by default download to the same folder. But when running through a particular site, it is still downloading to the user generic 'Downloads' folder as if those settings are being ignored.

Could this be a site driven issue or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Nope, and yep as an Answer to your 2 Qt's... => Related to your FCI as you are "probably" using v10.1.0 for CR 'Free' for which the 'ONDOWNLOAD' Command is not supported... (You need the 'PE' Version for that Command to work...)

Comment: I'm using an Enterprise License activated iMacros player.

Comment: Oh...!,  so you see that Behaviour also with iMB and not only with CR... Then I don't know...,  your OP is "too vague" from the "scarce" Info you've provided... Open a Ticket with 'TechSup' or a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum, I would say, and mention both FCI's and post some Script to reproduce...

Comment: chivracq I should add I'm seeing this behavior using Chrome w/o the iMacros extension and doing these same steps manually. Most of them work correctly but some are refusing to download one or more specific formats as anything other than a .txt file.

Comment: FYI: I've mentioned/linked to this current Thread in the following Thread on the iMacros Forum for #TechSup to have a look as you are the 4th User reporting a "similar" Issue...: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=31192&p=86452#p86452 (All Items I mentioned in my Post about "Low Quality" also apply to this current Thread... (Hum, except "Follow-up" maybe...))